# Using Guava's Tables.toTable

Tags: java, guava

I have a List of `Thing` holding two atrributes : `status` (an Enum) and `owner` (another object).

I want to obtain a Guava `Table<owner, status, Long>` by traversing the `ArrayList` and counting the objects, including a count of `0` if some status isn't in the List, like that:

```
[owner1, status1, 2], [owner1, status2, 0], [owner2, status1, 3], [owner2, status2, 2]
```

how to use `.collect(Tables.toTable())` in that case?

Comment: Can you show sample input list with values and how do you obtain count?

Comment: to obtain the table I used in my example, The list of Thing would be like that:

Thing1 (owner1, status1), Thing2 (owner2, status1), Thing3 (owner1, status1), Thing4 (owner2, status1), Thing5 (owner2, status1), Thing6 (owner2, status2), Thing7 (owner2, status2)

Comment: this could be done without the obfuscation of `.stream()` and would be more efficient in time and space and more readable and implicitly self-documenting as well. `.stream()` is the new `regex` of Java. Most times it is used it is not appropriate because those using it do not comprehend it.

Comment: Is there a way to know all the possible values for owner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code would create a table with counts, but **without zero-counts**.

```
List<Thing> listOfThings = ...;

Table<Owner, Status, Long> table = 
    listOfThings.stream().collect(
        Tables.toTable(
            Thing::getOwner,             // Row key extractor
            Thing::getStatus,            // Column key extractor
            thing -> 1,                  // Value converter (a single value counts '1')
            (count1, count2) -> count1 + count2, // Value merger (counts add up)
            HashBasedTable::create       // Table creator
        )
    );
```

To add the missing cells into the table (with zero-values), you would need to additionally iterate though all the possible values (of `Status` and `Owner`), and put the 0-value if there's no value yet. Note that, if `Owner` isn't an enum, there's no trivial way to get all of its possible values.

Or alternatively, instead of doing this, just check for `null`s when retrieving values from the table.

Comment: I tried your solution, but in the first parameter of toTable() I can't access getOwner(). It seems eclipse is treating the variable thing as Object instead of Thing...

Comment: Does the class `Thing` have the method named `getOwner()`? or is it just a public field `owner`?

Comment: Nevermind. I see that you have edited your answer. In this new version the code works. Thanks!

Comment: If you decide to mark an answer as accepted, you can click the __grey checkbox near the votes count,__ in the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide mappers for the rows, columns, values, a merging function and a table supplier. So something like this:

```
list.stream().collect(Tables.toTable(
               Thing::getStatus,
               Thing::getOwner,
               t -> 1, //that's your counter
               (i, j) -> i + j, //that's the incrementing function
               HashBasedTable::create //a new table
            ));
```